# iOS BLE background reconnection

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a problem with background reconnection with device. When I leave BLE device area, leave the iPhone for about 3 min and wait for background then go back, it won't reconnect. I tried to scan for peripheral in background but it isn't working even when I specified UUID. Is there any solution for that?

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.centralManager?.connectPeripheral(self.choosenPeripheral!, options: nil)  
        })    
   }
```

Comment: You need to show some code, but essentially when you get a call to the `didDisconnect` delegate method you should immediately call `connect` on the peripheral. Then, when it comes back into range you will reconnect to it.

Comment: I call connect in didDisconnect: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d84ec2b18f9937d86d6ca44e6e3aa708
I set choosen peripheral after first connection, I also tried put connection in 
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48327137/edit) your question to show relevant code.

Comment: You don't need the `Dispatch`.  All you need is `centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)`.  Make sure you have the appropriate Bluetooth background mode enabled on your app capabilities.  You also need to opt in to Bluetooth state restoration for long-term background operations so that iOS can relaunch your app if required.  Do not use a `UIViewController` to hold your `CBCentralManager` and related properties. Use another class that is held by your AppDelegate or implemented as a Singleton.

Comment: I store it in singleton. I will try without dispatch and reply after tests. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for help! I have removed dispatch and now everything is working! You could write your comment as an answer if you want to

Comment: Hi, today I left phone out of the BLE device area for about 10 minutes. Unfortunately after this period of time app didn't reconnect with device

Comment: Have you correctly implemented BLE state restoration?

Comment: I only have: **self.centralManager?.connectPeripheral(self.choosenPeriphera‌​‌​l!, options: nil)** in **willRestoreState**. I put there also notification to home view for changing label text to see if method was called, but it wasn't This method is only called when I close app and launch it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the peripheral disconnects, you simply need to call `connectPeripheral` again in the `didDisconnectPeripheral` delegate method; This will create a "pending" connection and as soon as the peripheral comes back into range iOS will connect to it and call your `didConnectPeripheral` delegate method.

You don't need to `Dispatch` the connect operation.  Just use:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        central.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)    
}
```

Comment: Is there no timeout for this pending reconnect? I have an app that does this but it seems it only re-establishes the connection if the peripheral is back in range within some amount of time. Back in range several hours later does not seem to re-establish the connection for me. Bringing the app to foreground and calling connect() does re-establish the connection so it does not seem to be the peripheral going into some low-power state.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know about the timeout yet but my guess is that it will not timeout.

Comment: You need to make sure you have opted in to Bluetooth state restoration otherwise the connect won't complete if your app is no longer running